# Analysis: Proving inequalities for terms and limit of sequence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $a_n \to a$ and $A \leqslant a_n \leqslant B$

Then how would I prove  $A \leqslant a \leqslant B$

Comment: So, $a_n\in[a,b]$ for all $n$. $[a,b]$ is closed, so it contains all of its limit points. $a$ is a limit point.

Comment: @DonThousand Proving that $[a,b]$ is closed, and that a closed set contains the limit points of its sequences is as hard and contains all the substance of the original problem.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I didn't provide a proof. I provided a framework of a proof. Otherwise, I'd post it as an answer.